# Actionscript 3 child from array not recognized

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I'm very new to actionscript and I'm still trying to figure out arrays and classes.  I'm making a game kind of like the bonus round from [Shinobi](https://youtu.be/Soyt3nTDfQ4?t=125) but I'm using bats that fly into the stage, fly vertically out of the stage, and then land back into the stage but closer. Here is the code for adding the bats to the scene:

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.BackgroundColor;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

public class PlayScreen extends MovieClip
{
    public var background:Background;
    public var batArmy:Array;
    public var addBatTimer:Timer;

    public function PlayScreen() 
    {
        background = new Background
        background.x = 0;
        background.y = 0;
        addChild( background );
        batArmy = new Array();
        var newBat = new Bat( 480, -50);
        batArmy.push (newBat);
        addChild (newBat);
        addBatTimer = new Timer(7000,2)
        addBatTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addBat);
        addBatTimer.start();
    }
    public function addBat( e:Event ):void
    {
        var newBat = new Bat( 480, -50);
        batArmy.push ( newBat )
        addChild (newBat);
    }
}
```

All of the bat's movements are in another class called Bat.

I'm having two problems:

Problem #1:  A bat that is close up will still be behind a bat that is further away.

Problem #2:  I add `setChildIndex(PlayScreen.newBat, 0)` to the contructor code of Class Bat and `setChildIndex(PlayScreen.newBat, 1)` when the bat gets closer but I'm getting "Access of possibly undefined property newBat through a reference with static type Class."

It seems that newBat is defined in PlayScreen class so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? Like I said before I'm very new to this and am pretty much self taught so I might be doing something completely wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PlayScreen.newBat` means an attempt to access a `public static var newBat` in your `PlayScreen` class. The `newBat` variable is created locally inside the function and so it is visible only there.
As far as I understand the first problem — your newly added bats need to be behind previously added ones:

```
addChild (newBat);
setChildIndex(newBat, 0);
```

in the `addBat` function should help.
When the bat gets closer (which seems to be handled inside the `Bat` class) if you need just to add it to the top depth:

```
if(parent){//I prefer checking it - just in case
    parent.setChildIndex(this, parent.numChildren - 1);
}
```

Another way is to create a child layer `Sprite` in your `PlayerScreen` for each bat distance and add every bat to that `Sprite` as it comes closer.

**UPDATE**
to make your `PlayScreen` instance visible for the `Bat` you need to pass a reference there. One of the simplest ways is to add one more parameter to the `Bat` constructor like this:
`Bat` class:

```
private var _screen: PlayerScreen;
public function Bat(xVal:int, yVal:int, screen:PlayerScreen){
    //...
    _screen = screen;
}
```

`PlayerScreen` class:

```
var newBat = new Bat( 480, -50, this);
```

and every `public` member of `PlayerScreen` will be available from the `Bat` like e. g. `_screen.background`

Comment: Awesome, that worked for the closest distance!  I also have a Mid distance and far distance, which is posing a problem.  When I do parent.setChildIndex(this, 1) for the Mid distance I get a #2006:out of bounds error.  Also, whenever I tell something in Bat Class to effect something that's in the Playscreen class I get an error saying the variable isn't recognized so I can't get the Sprite idea to work.  I feel like I'm missing something really fundamental as far as that goes.  Thank you very much for your help so far!

Comment: That update did it!!!  I created 4 movie clips called Layer01, Layer02, Layer03, and Layer04 in PlayScreen.  Then I added the background to Layer01 in the constructor.  The new bats got added to Layer 02.  When it got to the part in the move sequence for the bat to get closer, in the Bat class I put: 'parent.removeChild( this )' and then '_screen.Layer03.addChild ( this )'.  When it got even closer I put 'parent.removeChild( this )' and then ' _screen.Layer04.addChild ( this )'.  Worked like a charm, thank you so much!